# Optaplanner: How to calculate score delta for move

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner to automatically solve school timetables. After a timetable has been solved the user will manually change some lessons and will get feedback on how this affects the score via the following call:

```
scoreManager.updateScore(timetable);
```

This call takes some 200ms and will, I assume, do a complete evaluation. Im trying to optimize this and want to only pass in a Move object so that Optaplanner only has to recalculate the delta, like:

```
scoreManager.updateScore(previousTimetable,changeMove);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way how to do just a single move. You don't do moves - the solver does moves. You can only make external problem changes to the solution. You should look into [the `ProblemChange` interface](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#problemChange) and its use in the [`SolverManager`](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#solverManager).

However, the problem change will likely reset the entire working solution anyway. And after the external change is done, you're not guaranteed that the solution will still make sense. (What if it breaks hard constraints now?) You simply need to expect and account for the fact that, after users submit their changes, the solver will need to run; possibly even for a prolonged period of time.